# How much more can I contribute to my 401(k) this year after I made some Roth IRA, Roth 401k, and 401k contributions?

Tags: united-states, 401k, roth-ira, contribution, roth-401k

I've just started a new job, and would like to max out my pre-tax 401(k) contributions before year end.  I have contributed to various other investment accounts earlier this year and am struggling to figure out how much more I can contribute without going over the contribution limit.

My details are as follows:

```
Married, Filing Jointly

Gross Income < $100k

Roth IRA Contributions Year to Date: $5500

Roth 401(k) Contributions Year to Date: $1100

Pre-Tax 401(k) Contributions Year to Date: $1000
```

Given this info, how much more do I need to contribute to hit the $17,500 max for year end?

Specific questions include:

Do my Roth 401(k) contributions count towards my annual 401(k) contribution limits or are they separate?  Roth IRA contributions are separate from both types of 401(k)'s right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the 2014 tax year, you can contribute $17500 to a Roth 401K *or* pre-tax 401K with your income level if you are under 50. Both pre-tax and Roth 401K contributions count toward the $17500 total, so you would need to contribute $15400 to hit the maximum contribution for 2014.

More info is here: http://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/Roth-Comparison-Chart (the note at the bottom of the table explains combined contributions)

Your IRA contributions do not count toward your 401K total.

Comment: "Roth or regular 401K" should be "Roth or pre-tax 401K". It doesn't include post-tax 401k.

Comment: Good point, edited.